# Speeding a wordpress website (specially on mobile)

Tags: php, css, wordpress, mobile-website, pagespeed

I have a question regarding speeding my WordPress website running under nginx. Important information because I want to implement suggestions from Pingdom, Yellowlab and Google PageSpeed.

Pingdom suggests: Add Expires headers, Make fewer HTTP requests, Reduce DNS lookups.

YellowLabs says the CSS of my website isn't good (bad CSS, CSS complexity and webfonts). Google suggests I remove the CSS I don't need. I found a website called PurifyCSS which seemed to do the trick but it broke my site.

Anyway, I tried to add expire headers to my website but all information are for Apache. And it seems my website uses nginx. I couldn't find any precise information about nginx (Apache is easy: modify *.htaccess*).

Long story short: Can someone help me fulfill the suggestions of Pingdom and give me a clue about the CSS of my website?

Additional information: it seems an empty WordPress website has already css problems. Which is not the case of a blog made with Blogger or Ghost:

- http://musicinsightsorg.wordpress.com/
- http://soundssirius.blogspot.com/

What I really need is maybe a WordPress plugin dealing with those 4 issues, or maybe some PHP code I can add to my *functions.php*. The optimization is important for mobile.

For the specific guidance I received, here are the tests I've made

- [Pingdom Website Speed Test](https://tools.pingdom.com/#5c581c98e8000000)
- [Google PageSPeed Test](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsoundsirius.blog%2F&tab=mobile)
- [YellowLab](https://yellowlab.tools/result/fmcpx2twmi)

Answer (score 0):

For one, I would take a look in your browser's inspector. There are some JavaScript errors you need to fix. Also there are unauthorised calls to momently that you need to fix.
I would also serve minified versions of CSS and JS files. For example you serve jquery unminified: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsoundsirius.blog%2F&tab=mobile
Defer loading of Stripe too.

Also try Hummingbird to help with expiry headers and other optimisations: https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/wp-hummingbird/

Comment: I installed a plugin to minify styles and scripts. My desktop version was green in google after that and the mobile version was twice as fast!!!! BUT... images didn't load anymore and stripe payments stopped working.